# Execute failed: SyntaxError: syntax error near '” OVER c' occurs when executing a simple statement

Tags: nebula-graph

I'm using Nebula version 1.0 and attempting to execute a command in a specific space. The command I am running is:

```
GO FROM "player102" OVER call
```

However, an exception is being thrown with the following error message:

```
E0427 17:40:11.934425 66754 ExecutionPlan.cpp:23] Do cmd GO FROM "player102" OVER call' failed: SyntaxError: syntax error near " OVER c’
E0427 17:40:11.934618 66754 ExecutionPlan.cpp:76] Execute failed: SyntaxError: syntax error near `" OVER c’
```

The error suggests that there is a syntax error near the phrase " OVER c’. Please review the syntax of my command.